# How can I get our commit-message policy to stop preventing me from deleting branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, githooks

We have a Git commit-message policy in our repository: every commit message should include a "`Reviewer:`" field.

The problem is that, when I try to delete a branch with the `git push --delete` command, I get the following error:

```
remote: fatal: git cat-file 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000: bad file
remote: fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
remote: fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
remote: The commit message must include Reviewer: The reviewer name
remote: Please use commit --amend to add Reviewer: The reviewer name
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/versions/oldDesign
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Change your hook script to detect branch deletes / delete the branch on the server directly.